# Nested fibonacci?

Tags: nested, fibonacci

First off this is for school and I'm not looking for a handout.  Just guidance.
I need to write a fibonacci function using very basic tools.

I have these tools (from a language we wrote in Java):

- if-else
- for-loop
- arithmetic
- assignment
- infinite nesting
- any number of statements.

The problem is any nest or statement can only have one resultant statement or nest.

For example, this is okay:

```
repeat b to 7 by 2
{
  repeat a to 5 by 1
  {
    a = a + 1
  }
}
```

but this is not okay:

```
repeat x to 5 by 1
{
  x = x + 1
  y = x
}
```

Here is the relevant section of the grammar:

```
<code> ::= <statement> <code>
<code> ::= <statement>
<statement> ::= load <string>
<statement> ::= print <expr>
<statement> ::= input <var>
<statement> ::= if <cond> <statement>
<statement> ::= if <cond> <statement> else <statement>
<statement> ::= repeat <var> to <val> by <val>
<statement> ::= <var> = <expr>
<expr> ::= <val> + <val>
<expr> ::= <val> - <val>
<expr> ::= <val> * <val>
<expr> ::= <val> / <val>
<expr> ::= <val>
<cond> ::= <val> == <val>
<cond> ::= <val> > <val>
<cond> ::= <val> < <val>
<val> ::= <num>
<val> ::= <var>
```

I can't figure out how the heck I'm going to get this done.  Recursion is not allowed.
Any pointers?

Again, not looking for the solution, just guidance.

Thanks so much

Comment: posting the language grammar would make this easier to answer.

Comment: good point.  Added.

Comment: does an if-else statement count as one or 2 statements?

Comment: if-else is one statement and can be infinitely nested as well

Comment: Are you allowed to have more than one top-level statement?

Comment: Yes, any number of top-level statements.  (edited grammar)

Comment: You could insert loop statements that only execute once, but I doubt this is what your teacher had in mind as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? use 3 variables that represent the last 3 numbers of the sequence?.  What you really want is to have a simple:

```
a = 0
b = 1
repeat x to 5 by 1
{
   c = a + b
   a = b
   b = c
}
```

But this is not allowed.  However, since if-else counts as 1 statement, you can simply (ab)use this to do 3 statements by doing 1 statement in each part of a repeat:

```
a = 0
b = 1
repeat x to 5 by 1
{
   repeat y to 3 by 1
   {
       if y < 2
       {
            if y < 1
            {
                c = a + b
            }
            else
            {
                a = b
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            b = c
        } 
   }
}
```

Comment: They said in the question that multiple statements are not allowed within a single block.

Comment: Fixed logic.  The next question is are the loops zero based or 1 based?  is repeat x to 5 by 1 equivalent to for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, loops can start anywhere and yes that is the equivalent for-loop.

Comment: Where did my "Answer Your Question" comment go?!  Thank you guys so much.  I was so close with the (ab)used if-else but I couldn't figure out how to control it.       Turns out you can control a three-statement block with a three-count loop !!     Thanks again!!